# AngularJS - How to pass data through nested (custom) directives from child to parent

Tags: angularjs, scope, nested, directive

I am looking to find the best way of sending scope through nested directives.

I have found that you can do `$scope.$parent.value`, but I understood that's not a best practice and should be avoided.

So my question is, if I have 4 nested directives like below, each with it's own controller where some data is being modified, what's the best way to access a value from directive4 (let's say `$scope.valueFromDirective4`) in directive1?

```
<directive1>
    <directive2>
        <directive3>
            <directive4>
            </directive4>
        </directive3>
    </directive2>
</directive1>
```

Comment: Are these directives "smart" in the sense that they can know about your app and its services? Or do you want to make these directives truly decoupled from the app and reusable (you just pass them the data they need through attributes). And if they can't know about your app, can they know about each other?

Comment: let's say directive1 and 2 are smart, whilst directives 3,4 just show some elements on the screen (we could consider them some input fields which hold some data that needs to be accessed in directives 1 and 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the "presentational" / "dumb" components (`directive3` and `directive4`), I think they should each take in a callback function which they can invoke with new data when they change:

```
scope: {
    // Invoke this with new data
    onChange: '&',
    // Optional if you want to bind the data yourself and then call `onChange`
    data: '='
}
```

Just pass the callback down from `directive2` through `directive4`. This way `directive3` and `directive4` are decoupled from your app and reusable.

If they are form-like directives (similar to `input` etc), another option is to look into having them require `ngModel` and have them use `ngModelController` to update the parent and view. (Look up `$render` and `$setViewValue` for more info on this). This way you can use them like:

```
<directive4 ng-model="someObj.someProp" ng-change="someFunc()"></directive4>
```

When you do it like this, after the model is updated the `ng-change` function is automatically invoked.

For the "container" / "smart" directives (`directive1` and `directive2`), you could also have `directive2` take in the callback which is passed in from `directive1`. But since `directive1` and `directive2` can both know about your app, you could write a service which is injected and shared between `directive1` and `directive2`.

Answer (score 0):

Nested directives can always have an access to their parents' controllers via `require`. Let's say you want to change `value` from the `directive1`'s scope from any of its nested directives. One of the possible ways to achieve that is to declare a setter in the `directive1`'s controller `setValue(value)`. Then in any of nested directives you need to require the `directive1`'s controller and by doing that you'll get an access to the setter `setValue(value)` and other methods the controller provides.

```
angular
  .module('yourModule')
  .directive('directive1', function() {
    return {
      controller:['$scope', funciton($scope) {
        return {
          setValue: setValue
        };

        funciton setValue(value) {
          $scope.value = value;
        }
      }]
      // The rest of the directive1's configuration
    };
  })
  .directive('directive4', function() {
    return {
      require: '^^directive1',
      link: (scope, elem, attrs, directive1Ctrl) {
        // Here you can call directive1Ctrl.setValue() directly
      }
      // The rest of the directive4's configuration
    };
  })
```

Another way is to `$emit` events from a child directive's controller whenever `value` is changed by the child. In this case the parent directive's controller should subscribe to that event and handle the data passed along with it.

Comment: This still seems to be a bit over the hand with the require method - haven't really seen this until now. Currently, I have found a solution which seems to be better according to some articles in which I define a function in directive1 and pass it as an attribute down the nested directives. This way I can call the function in directive4 with a parameter which holds the data I want to edit in directive 1.

Comment: @MihaiBanu perhaps write your findings in a separate answer and let us have a look, please.